# Can't boot into any version of Ubuntu (always initramfs)

Tags: laptop, hp, initramfs

So, I got this laptop from my brother and I wanted to make it my Linux only machine. The machine is currently running Windows 10 so I wanted to change the OS to Linux and I experience this problem.

Every time I boot the installer (Ubuntu 16.10) I get the Ubuntu logo and the instantly I get this message:

(initramfs) mount: mount img /dev/loop0 on //filesystem.squashfs failed: invalid argument. Can not mount /dev/loop0 on //filesystem.squashfs

I tried installing other versions 16.04 , 11.10 also I tried Debian 8.6 and Ubuntu Mate and everywhere I get the same result.

Can someone here help me solve this?

Solutions that I was recommended and didn't work are changing USB in case it was corrupted and also Updating the BIOS. The model of the Laptop is: HP 15-r119nv

Comment: Could you confirm that secure boot is disabled?

Comment: Are you using a USB flash key for the Ubuntu Live installer? If you can burn the .iso to a DVD, and then boot that DVD, you might have better results. Also, I'd make it a dual-boot machine, and keep Windows 10 around so if you have to do things like BIOS updates, you'll have a way to do it.

Comment: @user48147 Yes Secure Boot is disabled , I double checked this a few minutes ago

Comment: @heynnema So I created a few bootable DVD with various versions of Ubuntu and I still had no luck, I only had "luck" with a Debian 8 Netinstaller which booted, I was able to install the system into a second partition but I couldn't boot into the system after the installation. So for now no solution for my problem :(

Comment: Your machine may just not be compatible with Linux. One last thought... did you check for BIOS updates at the HP web site?

Comment: @heynnema Yeah I updated the BIOS earlier today and the machine is compatible with Linux because the previous owner had Linux installed in it for nearly 6 months (Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome 3) and then switched it back to Windows 10.

Comment: Well, maybe you have a hardware problem. Go to http://www.memtest86.com/download.htm and download the free memtest86 memory tester, and give it a go.

Comment: @heynnema So I did the memtest86 (printscreen of the result HTML here: http://prntscr.com/dd1v8e) and there is nothing wrong with the hardware as it seems. I am coming to a dead end with this.

Comment: Are you booting the installer in EFI or Legacy mode?

Comment: @AndroidDev I tried in both , both failed.